# Dovecot lists no mail via telnet, even though there are mails available

Tags: ubuntu, exim, dovecot, email-server

So I am currently running dovecot as a mail delivery agent, and a little while ago it all strangely stopped working (I think this may have been about the time I ran out of space on my server - since resolved). When I telnet into the server and List the mail messages I get:

```
LIST
+OK 0 messages:
.
```

But when I look in /var/mail/ mail is listed and if I type in 'mail' I get a list of unread messages, how come this list is not showing in telnet?

I found a single post where someone is encountering a similar problem [here](http://old.nabble.com/0-mails-available-even-if-mails-in-mailbox-td23097580.html)

Where they recommend:

> After I deleted the dovecot.index
>   file, all messages are available and 
>   everything works as expected.everything works as expected.

However, this had no effect for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is dovecot configured to store mail in `/var/mail/` ? It does not necessarily store mail there. Check your dovecot configuration.

Comment: Slaps forehead - thanks for that, dovecot somehow got changed so that it was looking in a different location.